# Invalid input values for pname while trying to get the table preference

Tags: sql, oracle

here is the sql query i am trying to run to get the TABLE_CACHED_BLOCKS preference

**select dbms_stats.get_prefs ( pname=>'TABLE_CACHED_BLOCKS', ownname=>user, tabname=>'bricks_idx1' ) from dual;**

I am getting the following error message

**ORA-20001: Invalid input values for pname**

help me in finding the solution ..

I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: 11g does not have pname 'TABLE_CACHE_BLOCKS' available. Refer section: "Table 140-50 GET_PREFS" at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#BEICCEDB

Comment: @Pankaj , thanks for your reply just want to know does 11g supports clustering factor or similar technique? , if it does then how it is implemented if you know then please help me .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do or what issue are you trying to resolve? Clustering factor is a generic term.

Comment: @Pankaj , actually i want to increase the TABLE_CACHE_BLOCKS table pref from 1 to 16 so that optimizer will not increase the clustering factor when it is not finding the data in 16 consecutive block and at the end instead of doing full table scan it will use index  , i hope you got the point..